# Recorrido en filas y columnas en un array Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Señores necesito recorrer las filas y columnas de una tabla alimentada por un array, en la columna debo encontrar en numero mayor y restarlo por cada valor en esa columna, luego comparar toda la fila y crear al final una nueva columna que con el valor máximo. por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente matriz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la opción `Que de no se adapte` se deberá escoger el numero `1000` y restarlo a toda la columna de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo escoger de cada fila el valor máximo (Vm) y agregarlo en una nueva columna al final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tener en cuenta que el array es dinámico, yo estaba intentando esto, pero me he quedado estancado:

```html
let obj = [
    { 1: 47, 2: 89, 3: 9, 4: 23 },
    { 1: 97, 2: 1, 3: 30, 4: 53 },
    { 1: 40, 2: 25, 3: 19, 4: 41 }
];


let maxCols = {}
obj.map((c,i) => {
    let fila = Object.values(c)
    let max = Math.max(...fila)
    obj[i]['max'] = max;
    for (let x = 0; x < fila.length; x++) {
        if(!maxCols[(x+1).toString()] || fila[x] > maxCols[(x+1).toString()]) maxCols[(x+1).toString()] = fila[x];
    }
})

obj.push(maxCols);

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez sea un poco tarde para la respuesta pero espero que te sea de utilidad. Como primer punto no veo necesario el uso de objetos, usando arrays puedes lograr el objetivo y por cómo planteas el problema, parece ser lo más adecuado. He hecho tres funciones para representar cada uno de los pasos que describes.

1. Buscar el máximo de una columna.
2. Restar ese máximo a su columna respectiva.
3. Buscar el máximo por fila y agregar una nueva columna.

Utilizando el ejemplo que utilizas y también usando el ejemplo que ocupas en código (demostrando que puede ser dinámico) el código sería algo así:

```js
const array1 = [
  [650, 550, 900],
  [1000, 650, 400],
  [500, 800, 950]
];

const array2 = [
  [47, 89, 9, 23],
  [97, 1, 30, 53],
  [40, 25, 19, 41]
];

const encontrarMaximosPorColumna = array => {
  return array.reduce((acc, valorActual) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      if (valorActual[i] > acc[i]) {
        acc[i] = valorActual[i];
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, new Array(array[0].length).fill(0));
};

const restarMaximosPorColumna = (original, maximos) => {
  return original.reduce((acc, valorActual) => {
    acc.push(valorActual.map((n, idx) => maximos[idx] - n));
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

const agregarColumna = (original, nuevaColumna) => {
  original.map((fila, idx) => {
    fila.push(Math.max.apply(null, nuevaColumna[idx]));
  });
};

let maximos, restaDeMaximos;

maximos = encontrarMaximosPorColumna(array1);
console.log('Máximos: ', maximos);
restaDeMaximos = restarMaximosPorColumna(array1, maximos);
console.log('Diferencia: ', restaDeMaximos);
agregarColumna(array1, restaDeMaximos);
console.log('Final:', array1);

maximos = encontrarMaximosPorColumna(array2);
console.log('Máximos: ', maximos);
restaDeMaximos = restarMaximosPorColumna(array2, maximos);
console.log('Diferencia: ', restaDeMaximos);
agregarColumna(array2, restaDeMaximos);
console.log('Final:', array2);
```

El código tiene áreas de oportunidad, como el hecho de que se da por entendido de que todas las filas siempre tienen el mismo número de elementos, por lo que agregando esa validación el código se haría más robusto aún.